# Calculate support of a itemset

Tags: python

How to implement the function that support to calculate the support of a given rule on a set of transactions.

```
def support(rule, transactions):
    pass
```

Where `rule` is a list of two sets, representing the  X→YX→Y rule and
`transactions` is a list of transactions

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to do a loop on the set of transactions. In that loop you compare the rule X->Y  with each transaction. If the rule X->Y appear in the transaction, you increase its support by 1. After the two loops terminate, you have the support of the rule.

Comment: thank you but how  do u write it in python the question is practical a question 6 and 7[link](https://kmurphy.bitbucket.io/modules/Discrete_Mathematics/topics/50-Resources_for_Student_Repeating_this_Module/index.html#21-Practical_A_-_Association_Rule_Mining)